# Значение понятия "провинция"

Tags: значение-слов, семантика, многозначность

Всякое ли поселение, не являющееся областным центром, является провинцией? Например, можем ли мы назвать провинцией микрорайон Железнодорожный, который находится неподалёку от Москвы (столицы)?

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/провинция. Можем ли назвать: скорее нет чем да.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сегодня понятия **провинция** вообще нет, это анахронизм, устаревшее понятие.

Обратимся к Словарю русского языка: В 4-х т. / РАН, Ин-т лингвистич. исследований; Под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой. — 4-е изд., стер. — М.: Рус. яз.; Полиграфресурсы, 1999:

> ПРОВИ́НЦИЯ, -и, ж.
>
> 1. Ист. Завоеванная древними римлянами территория, управлявшаяся римским наместником.
> 2. Ист. Административно-территориальная единица в России в 18 в., часть губернии.
> 3. Административно-территориальная единица в некоторых государствах. Оказывается, сто лет назад в Японии губернаторы головой отвечали за
>    все, происходящее в их провинциях, — за тайфуны, землетрясения, дожди.
>    Аграновский, Призвание.
> 4. Устар. Отдаленная от столицы, центра местность; периферия. В провинции все веяния доходят поздно, и новый реакционный курс --- до
>    Красноярска еще не дошел. Короленко, История моего современника.
>    [Треплев:] Дебютировала она под Москвой в дачном театре, потом уехала
>    в провинцию. Чехов, Чайка.

https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D

Слово происходит от латинского «provincia». В Древнем Риме так назывались подвластные Риму территории, находящиеся вне Апеннинского полуострова и управлявшиеся римскими наместниками, то есть иностранные территории. Попадает в Россию оно в конце XVII в. как  калька с польского provincja,  т.е.,  воеводство,  губерния.    Первое  официальное  употребление зафиксировано в договоре Петра I с маркизом Кармартеном от 16 апреля 1698 г., где, говоря о своем намерении разводить в России “никоциан”,  бывшее Казанское царство он  называет провинцией  Казанской, используя  слово  как  подходящий  к  случаю неологизм. В 1699 г. Указом от 27 октября   Петр объявляет провинциями три области с центрами в Новгороде, Астрахани и Пскове.
https://studylib.ru/doc/2227861/-russkaya-provinciya----istoriya-slova-i-ponyatiya-

**В 1775 г. более чем полувековая история административной области и термина провинция закончилась**. Все пространство России было поделено на губернии и уезды.

В 1840-м  г.  будет  закреплено противопоставление: **провинция↔столица**. В Словаре церковно-славянского и русского языка 1847 г. весь комплекс производных от провинции форм уже фигурирует как единое понятие с означаемой территорией в виде области или округа и  культурной  идеологией, закрепляющей  противостояние  провинции  и столицы. Эта версия будет канонизирована В. Далем в его Толковом словаре живого великорусского языка: “Провинция – губерния, область, округ, уезд; провинциал - живущий не в столице, житель губернии, уезда, захолустья”.

Понятие *провинция*, как и многое другое, перешло  в  разряд анахронизмов. Слово  продолжало  бытовать  в  языке,  но  уже  с выхолощенной семантикой, т.к. стремительно исчезала питавшая его реальность. Новая реальность требовала нового названия. В 1937 г. в главном печатном  органе  страны  газете  “Правда”  появилась  статья  под  названием “Периферия”. Эпиграф к статье гласил: “–Провинция, это где?–Нигде... Ее Гоголь выдумал.  (Из  разговора  третьеклассников)”.  В  качестве  образца  “преображенной” провинции был выбран Муром, жители которого, в основном интеллигенция (!), ни словом “не намекнули, что скучна, однообразна жизнь в районном центре. Даже крепко поругивая Муром, ни один из этих людей не произнес обидных слов – провинция, глушь, захолустье, столь употребительных прежде по отношению к уездным городам. Нет захолустья, –утверждала статья.–Есть периферия, где люди работают так же настойчиво,  дружно  самоотверженно,  как  и  в  центре.
Что  же  до  «унылого  слова “провинция”», то оно «потеряло право на местожительство в нашей стране. Когда сегодня хотят упомянуть о пунктах, отдаленных от центра, говорят – периферия. Это точное, никому не обидное слово».

Так что теперь слово ещё употребляется в значении "Местность, находящаяся вдали от столицы, крупного культурного центра", но не как официальное понятие, а как символ косности, отсталости. Есть такие москвичи, которые называют провинцией всё, что не относится к Москве. Видимо, это отголосок того, что Москва живёт своей жизнью, это государство в государстве, на которое работают все остальные территории.

**Административно-территориальной единицы такой нет.** Если же Ваш  вопрос отнести к понятию **периферия**, то *микрорайон Железнодорожный, который находится неподалеку от Москвы (столицы)?,* никак **не удалён от столицы**, это понятие тоже к нему **нельзя применить**.